# Why does Apiary.io call take so long under Chrome

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome, apiary.io, apiary

I've got a jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/netroworx/3ea5a/

Html is:

```
<div ng-app>
<div ng-controller="AjaxCtrl">
    {{result}}
</div>
</div>
```

Javascript is:

```
function AjaxCtrl($scope, $http) {
    $scope.result = "ABC";

    $scope.data = { "title": "My note" };

    $http.post('http://jsfiddle.apiary-mock.com/notes', $scope.data).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.result = JSON.stringify(data);
    }).error(function (data, status) {
        $scope.result = "Error";
    });

}
```

It makes a call to an Apiary.io mock

On my Mac under Chrome v34 the call seems to take several minutes to come back.

Using Safari or Firefox the call comes back within a second or so.

The Chrome network tab in the developer tools shows the request as pending for those several minutes.

Please help.

Comment: Chrome v34, Firefox and Internet Explorer work under Windows 7 - the problem seems to be limited to Chrome under OSX. I'm using Mavericks.

Comment: If you use chrome inspector you can see, chrome make 2 requests (options, post) for this action. Firefox make only POST request.

Comment: Greg - could you pop open your Developer Tools (cmd-alt-i), switch to the Network tab, run the slow API call in question and post the results here?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by running slow request from Network tab. I selected Replay XHR from the request in the network tab. Response does not seem to come back yet. The OPTIONS call is based on the CORS specification. The apiary.io mock has been set to allow CORS

Comment: Ajax returns after 3.5 minutes according to Chrome network tab

Comment: @GregPagendam-Turner That is extremely strange, as we are on Heroku, which kills every long running requests after 30s, so 3.5min is extreme. Could you please post screenshot/breakdown of the network tab? Do you use any proxy? Could you send us a traceback for apiary-mock.com please? Feel free to hit support@apiary.io if you don't want to share those publicly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found the issue. Sophos antivirus was holding up the traffic to see if it was malicious.

I've disabled web scanning and the responses come back straight away.